# How do I get a value list from a tuple list?

Tags: haskell

I have a value sheet of type (x, y) and I would like to get an x sheet, but something goes wrong, here is the code:

```
x_list:: [(Double, Double)] -> [Double]
x_list list = Prelude.foldl(\t xl -> (fst t):xl) list []
```

I get this error:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type: (Double, b0)
                  with actual type: [Double]
    • In the first argument of ‘fst’, namely ‘t’
      In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(fst t)’
      In the expression: (fst t) : xl
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `foldl` instead of simply using `map`? (You can, of course, implement `map` in terms of `foldl`, but unless that's your assignment, I would just write `x_list = map fst`.)

Comment: @chepner, How can I implement this through the map?

Comment: @chepner, Oh, that's really better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in your code, both related to argument order:

[foldl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl), like all the other folds, takes the argument list as its *last* (3rd) argument and the starting accumulator (your `[]`) as the one before that - so you need to switch over the `list` and `[]` in your definition.

Similarly, the fold function itself has type `b -> a -> b` - that is it takes the old accumulator as its first element and the element of the list you're folding as its second. So in your case the first argument is a list of doubles and the second is a pair of doubles (not a list) - your implementation and variable names clearly imply you thought it was the other way round, but the compiler can't accept this.

(Note that for a right fold the argument order is reversed. This can be confusing - I always remember it by mentally placing the current accumulator at one end of the list: the left end for a left fold and the right end for a right fold, and then noting the fold function consumes its arguments in left-to-right order. Don't worry if this isn't helpful for you - I've probably explained it badly anyway. It's not essential, but it helps me!)

So your function when fixed in the above 2 ways will look like this:

```
x_list:: [(Double, Double)] -> [Double]
x_list list = Prelude.foldl(\xl t -> (fst t):xl) [] list
```

Note finally that this is much more simply and readably expressed with the `map` function - which (as you are doing here) applies a function to every element of a list. In this case the simplest definition would be

```
x_list list = map fst list
```

or, by "eta reduction", just:

```
x_list = map fst
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is `map` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map)

This takes a list and applies a given function to each element

```
xList :: [(Double,Double)] -> [Double]
xList = map fst
```

or a bit more explicit

```
xList' :: [(Double,Double)] -> [Double]
xList' list = map (\(x,y) -> x) list
```

Loading this into GHCi would give you

```
ghci> xList' [(1,2),(3,4)]
[1.0,3.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to work with a `map`:

```
x_list :: [(a, b)] -> [a]
x_list = map fst
```

you can also let this work for `foldr` with:

```
x_list :: [(a, b)] -> [a]
x_list list = foldr (\(t, _) xl -> t:xl) [] list
```

or with `foldl`, but this will work in quadratic time, and only produce a result when enumerated over all elements:

```
x_list :: [(a, b)] -> [a]
x_list list = foldl (\xl (t, _) -> xl ++ [t]) [] list
```